# Have a stack navigator always render initialRoute

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I'm building a react native app and I'm using react-navigation package. I have a tab navigator for the app and each tab has a stack navigator in it. Something like this:

```
const HomeStack = StackNavigation({
    Info: {screen: Info},
    Main: {screen: Main}
})

const SearchStack = StackNavigation({
    Search: {screen: Search},
    SearchResult: {screen: SearchResult}
})

TabNavigation({
  Home: {screen: HomeStack},
  Search: {screen: SearchStack}
})
```

So let's say I did a search and I'm now on SearchResult screen. I then go back to Home screen by pressing home tab. Now when I go back to search tab it shows me the SearchResult screen. Is there a way to force react-navigation to always render a Search screen when you go to it from the Tab?

I made a project on snack to illustrate this https://snack.expo.io/rkMzWoh17

Comment: How was this issue solved ? I am facing a similar issue right now

Answer (score 1):

use initial route name like this in searchstack  navigation like this

```
 {
    initialRouteName: 'Search',
  }
```

Comment: I do have that in my code, but it only works on initial render. Once I navigate around in the stack, it stores that screen in history and renders it when I go to the tab.

Comment: maybe pop all screens in the SearchStack then navigate to your Home Screen.  So when you navigate back to the stack it will start on the initial screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this inside every stack screen.

```
   const Search = ({ navigation }) => {
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
          const blur = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
            navigation.popToTop();
          });
      }, []);
   }
```

This pops the stack to the initial screen everytime you navigate away.

More information here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events